# How do I concatenate const/literal strings in C?

Tags: c, string, concatenation

I'm working in C, and I have to concatenate a few things.

Right now I have this:

```
message = strcat("TEXT ", var);

message2 = strcat(strcat("TEXT ", foo), strcat(" TEXT ", bar));
```

Now if you have experience in C I'm sure you realize that this gives you a segmentation fault when you try to run it. So how do I work around that?

Comment: I would like to suggest that you use strlcat instead of strcat! http://www.gratisoft.us/todd/papers/strlcpy.html

Comment: I would like to repeart That suggestion.  Strcat causes vulnerability to buffer overflow exploits.  Someone can give your program data that causes it to execute arbitrary code.

Answer (score 480, accepted):

In C, "strings" are just plain `char` arrays. Therefore, you can't directly concatenate them with other "strings".

You can use the `strcat` function, which appends the string pointed to by `src` to the end of the string pointed to by `dest`:

```
char *strcat(char *dest, const char *src);
```

Here is an [example from cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcat.html):

```
char str[80];
strcpy(str, "these ");
strcat(str, "strings ");
strcat(str, "are ");
strcat(str, "concatenated.");
```

For the first parameter, you need to provide the destination buffer itself.  The destination buffer must be a char array buffer.  E.g.: `char buffer[1024];`

**Make sure** that the first parameter has enough space to store what you're trying to copy into it.  If available to you, it is safer to use functions like: `strcpy_s` and `strcat_s` where you explicitly have to specify the size of the destination buffer.

*Note*: A string literal cannot be used as a buffer, since it is a constant. Thus, you always have to allocate a char array for the buffer.

The return value of `strcat` can simply be ignored, it merely returns the same pointer as was passed in as the first argument. It is there for convenience, and allows you to chain the calls into one line of code:

```
strcat(strcat(str, foo), bar);
```

So your problem could be solved as follows:

```
char *foo = "foo";
char *bar = "bar";
char str[80];
strcpy(str, "TEXT ");
strcat(str, foo);
strcat(str, bar);
```

Comment: Would you put "Be very careful that..." in bold, please?  This can't be stressed enough.  Misuse of strcat, strcpy, and sprintf are the heart of unstable/insecure software.

Comment: "static string" and "allocate your own buffer" may be misleading as the former could be interpreted to mean "static string buffer" and the latter to indicate dynamical allocation.  +1 if you change to "You can never use a string literal as a buffer, you must always use your own buffer" or similar.

Comment: Warning: As written, this code will leave a giant, gaping hole in your code for buffer overflow exploits.

Comment: There is no buffer overflow exploit possible in the above example.  And yes I agree in general I wouldn't use the above example for undetermined string lengths of foo and bar.

Comment: Don't use `strcat` multiple times! `strcat` has to check all the previous bytes (searching for `'\0'`) you already concatenated. This is useless processing.

Comment: To second @dolmen, Joel Spolsky has written [quite elaborate article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html) on the issue. Should be a mandatory reading. ;-)

Comment: Actually, string literals can be concatenated by just putting them side by side. e.g. `const char *str = "these" "strings" "are" "concatenated";`.

Comment: Shouldn't initial char buffer be initialized to zeros: `char str[80] = {0};`? This way you get a nice null-terminated string.

Comment: Please replace `strcat` and `strcpy` with their safer variants `strncat` and `strncpy`. Mentioning it in the text but not using it in the code itself isn't a good example.

Answer (score 295):

Avoid using [`strcat`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcat) in C code. The cleanest and, most importantly, the safest way is to use [`snprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/snprintf):

```
char buf[256];
snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%s%s%s%s", str1, str2, str3, str4);
```

Some commenters raised an issue that the number of arguments may not match the format string and the code will still compile, but most compilers already issue a warning if this is the case.

Comment: ... but without the needless and confusing parenthesis to the sizeof operator. Those are only needed when you want the size of an actual type, not of an object. Pet peeve alert, sorry.

Comment: This is arguably the best way to find out the size of the buffer, unless you are given a pointer. If you have a pointer, you will be passing the length of the buffer it points to with it.

Comment: Checkers, he was talking about the parentheses around "buf" of the sizeof argument. they are not required if the argument is an expression. But i don't understand why you are downvoted. i think your answer is the best of all, even though it is c99. (maybe because of that they disagree! lamers!) +1

Comment: Oh, reading comprehension -1. But anyway, I stand by my answer.

Comment: sizeof() only works here for char buf[...].  NOT for char  * buf = malloc(...).  There aren't many differences between arrays and pointers, but this is one of them!

Comment: Yes, hence my comment about dynamically allocated buffers.

Comment: Also, he is trying to perform concatenation. Concatenating using `snprintf()` is a BIG no no.

Comment: @Leonardo, can you tell use why?

Comment: Well, there is some risk that you add another, say, "str5" and forget an additional "%s" in the format string - or the other way around. Will only crash on you (if you are lucky) on runtime.  Besides it seems a bit overkill given the _safe_ alternatives of "strcat".

Comment: @Christian.K ah, but a decent compiler will warn you if you do this.

Comment: @MrRee: The differences between pointers and arrays are vast and complete! It's in how you _use_ them that does not always differ. Also, pointers and dynamic allocation are really orthogonal concepts.

Comment: what type `str1` `str2` should have? Can I use `std::string` or only `char*` is allowed?

Comment: @javapowered `%s` only expects `char*`.

Comment: One of my pet peeves is people like @unwind who insist on the pointless distinction between `sizeof(x)` and `sizeof x`.  The parenthesized notation always works and the unparenthesized notation only works sometimes, so always use the parenthesized notation; it is a simple rule to remember and is safe.  This gets into a religious argument — I've been involved in discussions with those who object before — but the simplicity of 'always use parentheses' outweighs any merit to not using them (IMNSHO, of course).  This is presented for balance.

Comment: agreed. lets not forget that sizeof should be interpreted as a function call. And that sizeof(x+1) and sizeof(x) + 1 are very different things

Comment: 1- Best answer, neat!. 2- For me sprintf works without `sizeof` as second argument. I found `int sprintf(char *str, const char *format, ...)` in  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sprintf.htm

Comment: Why `snprintf`? Why not `sprintf` instead?

Comment: @AndrewKoster for error-handling. In real code, you would [check the return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54084570/how-to-detect-snprintf-errors) to see if the buffer was large enough. `sprintf` just causes UB if the return value is not sufficiently large.

Comment: why is `snprintf` the "safest" way? what's wrong with `strncat`?

Answer (score 54):

Strings can also be concatenated at compile time.

```
#define SCHEMA "test"
#define TABLE  "data"

const char *table = SCHEMA "." TABLE ; // note no + or . or anything
const char *qry =               // include comments in a string
    " SELECT * "                // get all fields
    " FROM " SCHEMA "." TABLE   /* the table */
    " WHERE x = 1 "             /* the filter */ 
                ;
```

Answer (score 31):

Folks, use str**n**cpy(), str**n**cat(), or s**n**printf().

Exceeding your buffer space will trash whatever else follows in memory!

(And remember to allow space for the trailing null '\0' character!)

Comment: Not only should you remember to allow space for the NULL character, you need to remember to *add* the NULL character. strncpy and strncat don't do that for you.

Comment: Uh? strncpy() and strncat() sure add the terminating character. In fact, they add too many. At least as long as there's space left in the buffer, which is a huge trap with these calls. Not recommended.

Comment: @unwind, I think the point of Graeme is that if the buffer is too small, strncpy or strncat will _not_ add the terminating '\0'.

Comment: if n < strlen()+1,  no null is added.   if  n==strlen()+1, one null is added.   if n>strlen()+1 many nulls are added.  It's called PROGRAMMING.

Comment: Even better, prefer OpenBSD's strlcpy, strlcat (easy to port into your own project).

Comment: Right, I prefer strl*, too. But in this case I think your snprintf proposal is the best way.

Comment: snprintf is good, strncpy/strncat is the worst possible recommendation, strlcpy/strlcat is much better.

Comment: Don't use `strncpy()`.  It's *not* a "safer" version of `strcpy()`.  The target character array may be needlessly padded with extra `'\0'` characters, or worse, it may be left unterminated (i.e., not a string).  (It was designed for use with a data structure that's rarely used anymore, a character array padded to the end with zero or more `'\0'` characters.)

Comment: In `strncpy` and `strncat` this `n` is the max number of characters to copy, not the size of the target buffer. This and the non-terminated strings in case of truncation, and the different truncation handling on different platforms make it dangerous too. Please consider `strlcpy` and `strlcat`. See also my little article on this topic: https://gergap.wordpress.com/2013/04/05/ansi-c-string-handling-functions/

Answer (score 16):

Also malloc and realloc are useful if you don't know ahead of time how many strings are being concatenated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void example(const char *header, const char **words, size_t num_words)
{
    size_t message_len = strlen(header) + 1; /* + 1 for terminating NULL */
    char *message = (char*) malloc(message_len);
    strncat(message, header, message_len);

    for(int i = 0; i < num_words; ++i)
    {
       message_len += 1 + strlen(words[i]); /* 1 + for separator ';' */
       message = (char*) realloc(message, message_len);
       strncat(strncat(message, ";", message_len), words[i], message_len);
    }

    puts(message);

    free(message);
}
```

Comment: This will end in a endless loop when `num_words>INT_MAX`, maybe you should use `size_t` for `i`

Answer (score 7):

If you have experience in C you will notice that strings are only char arrays where the last character is a null character.

Now that is quite inconvenient as you have to find the last character in order to append something. `strcat` will do that for you.

So strcat searches through the first argument for a null character. Then it will replace this with the second argument's content (until that ends in a null).

Now let's go through your code:

```
message = strcat("TEXT " + var);
```

Here you are adding something to the pointer to the text "TEXT" (the type of "TEXT" is const char*. A pointer.).

That will usually not work. Also modifying the "TEXT" array will not work as it is usually placed in a constant segment.

```
message2 = strcat(strcat("TEXT ", foo), strcat(" TEXT ", bar));
```

That might work better, except that you are again trying to modify static texts. strcat is not allocating new memory for the result.

I would propose to do something like this instead:

```
sprintf(message2, "TEXT %s TEXT %s", foo, bar);
```

Read the documentation of `sprintf` to check for it's options.

And now an important point:

Ensure that the buffer has enough space to hold the text AND the null character. There are a couple of functions that can help you, e.g., strncat and special versions of printf that allocate the buffer for you.
Not ensuring the buffer size will lead to memory corruption and remotely exploitable bugs.

Comment: The type of `"TEXT"` is `char[5]`, *not* `const char*`.  It decays to `char*` in most contexts.  For backward compatibility reasons, string literals are not `const`, but attempting to modify them results in undefined behavior.  (In C++, string literals are `const`.)

Answer (score 7):

Best way to do it without having a limited buffer size is by using asprintf()

```
char* concat(const char* str1, const char* str2)
{
    char* result;
    asprintf(&result, "%s%s", str1, str2);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You should return `char *`, not `const char *`. The return value will need to be passed to `free`.

Comment: Unfortunately `asprintf` is only a GNU extension.

Answer (score 5):

It is undefined behaviour to attempt to modify string literals, which is what something like:

```
strcat ("Hello, ", name);
```

will attempt to do. It will try to tack on the `name` string to the end of the string literal `"Hello, "`, which is not well defined.

Try something this. It achieves what you appear to be trying to do:

```
char message[1000];
strcpy (message, "TEXT ");
strcat (message, var);
```

This creates a buffer area that *is* allowed to be modified and then copies both the string literal and other text to it. Just be careful with buffer overflows. If you control the input data (or check it before-hand), it's fine to use fixed length buffers like I have.

Otherwise, you should use mitigation strategies such as allocating enough memory from the heap to ensure you can handle it. In other words, something like:

```
const static char TEXT[] = "TEXT ";

// Make *sure* you have enough space.

char *message = malloc (sizeof(TEXT) + strlen(var) + 1);
if (message == NULL)
     handleOutOfMemoryIntelligently();
strcpy (message, TEXT);
strcat (message, var);

// Need to free message at some point after you're done with it.
```

Comment: What happens if var/foo/bar has more than 1000 characters? >:)

Comment: Then you will get a buffer overflow, which you can add code to check for beforehand (say, with strlen).  But the purpose of a code snippet is to show how something works without polluting it with too much extra code. Otherwise I'd be checking lengths, whether var/foo/bar was null, etc.

Comment: @paxdiablo: But you didn't even mention it, in an answer to a question where it would appear to need mentioning. That makes your answer **dangerous**. You also didn't explain why this code is better than the OP's original code, except for the myth that it "achieves the same result as your original" (then what would be the point? the original was _broken_!), so the answer is also **incomplete**.

Comment: Have hopefully addressed your concerns, @PreferenceBean, though in a less timely manner than ideal :-) Let me know if you still have a problem with the answer, and I'll improve it further.

Answer (score 5):

Do not forget to initialize the output buffer. The first argument to strcat must be a null terminated string with enough extra space allocated for the resulting string:

```
char out[1024] = ""; // must be initialized
strcat( out, null_terminated_string ); 
// null_terminated_string has less than 1023 chars
```

Answer (score 5):

As people pointed out string handling improved much. So you may want to learn how to use the C++ string library instead of C-style strings. However here is a solution in pure C

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void appendToHello(const char *s) {
    const char *const hello = "hello ";

    const size_t sLength     = strlen(s);
    const size_t helloLength = strlen(hello);
    const size_t totalLength = sLength + helloLength;

    char *const strBuf = malloc(totalLength + 1);
    if (strBuf == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "malloc failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    strcpy(strBuf, hello);
    strcpy(strBuf + helloLength, s);

    puts(strBuf);

    free(strBuf);

}

int main (void) {
    appendToHello("blah blah");
    return 0;
}
```

I am not sure whether it is correct/safe but right now I could not find a better way to do this in ANSI C.

Comment: `<string.h>` is C++ style.  You want `"string.h"`.  You also calculate `strlen(s1)` twice, which isn't needed.  `s3` should be `totalLenght+1` long.

Comment: @MooingDuck: `"string.h"` is nonsense.

Comment: I haven't used C-style strings for a while. Feel free to post a fixed version.

Comment: @MooingDuck: That's incorrect.  `#include <string.h>` is correct C.  Use angle brackets for standard and system headers (including `<string.h>`), quotation marks for headers that are part of your program.  (`#include "string.h"` will happen to work if you don't have your own header file by that name, but use `<string.h>` anyway.)

Comment: Note that this depends on C99-specific features: mixing declarations and statements, and variable-length arrays (VLAs).  Note also that VLAs provide no mechanism to detect or handle allocation failures; if there isn't enough room to allocate a VLA, your program's behavior is undefined.

Comment: Posted a fixed version, plz reconsider your voting.

Comment: You could safely use `strcat` rather than `strncat`, since you've already guaranteed that the target is big enough.

Comment: @KeithThompson agree, switched to just strcpy for now.

Comment: @KeithThompson: It's now worthy an upvote, turned my `-1` into a `+1`. (This answer was "inspired" by a discussion about C vs. C++ string handling in the C++ chat room. I think, Nils, that with this debacle you have quite effectively demonstrated your opponents' POV. `:^>`)

Answer (score 3):

The first argument of strcat() needs to be able to hold enough space for the concatenated string. So allocate a buffer with enough space to receive the result.

```
char bigEnough[64] = "";

strcat(bigEnough, "TEXT");
strcat(bigEnough, foo);

/* and so on */
```

strcat() will concatenate the second argument with the first argument, and store the result in the first argument, the returned char* is simply this first argument, and only for your convenience.

You do not get a newly allocated string with the first and second argument concatenated, which I'd guess you expected based on your code.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to copy a string into an address that is statically allocated. You need to cat into a buffer.

Specifically:

...snip...

destination

```
Pointer to the destination array, which should contain a C string, and be large enough to contain the concatenated resulting string.
```

...snip...

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcat.html

There's an example here as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own function that does the same thing as `strcat()` but that doesn't change anything:

```
#define MAX_STRING_LENGTH 1000
char *strcat_const(const char *str1,const char *str2){
    static char buffer[MAX_STRING_LENGTH];
    strncpy(buffer,str1,MAX_STRING_LENGTH);
    if(strlen(str1) < MAX_STRING_LENGTH){
        strncat(buffer,str2,MAX_STRING_LENGTH - strlen(buffer));
    }
    buffer[MAX_STRING_LENGTH - 1] = '\0';
    return buffer;
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    printf("%s",strcat_const("Hello ","world"));    //Prints "Hello world"
    return 0;
}
```

If both strings together are more than 1000 characters long, it will cut the string at 1000 characters. You can change the value of `MAX_STRING_LENGTH` to suit your needs.

Comment: I foresee buffer overflow, I see you allocated `strlen(str1) + strlen(str2)`, but you write `strlen(str1) + strlen(str2) + 1` characters. So can you really write your own function?

Comment: Wow! You never free the memory, nasty, nasty!
`return buffer;
    free(buffer);`

Comment: BTW, `sizeof(char) == 1`
(Besides, there are other more subtle errors ...)
Can you see now why you don't have to write your own function ?

Comment: @Liviu I do free the memory at the line `free(buffer);`.

Comment: @Duck you free the memory after exiting form the function ... so you do not free it

Comment: `char* mycat = strcat_const("Hello ","world");
free(mycat);`
There is a difference, isn't it ?

Comment: @Liviu Does that change anything? In that example, I think it would do the `printf("%s",strcat_const("Hello ","world"));` and then free the memory, so if you put more after that in the `main()` function it will free the memory before. Tell me if I'm wrong.

Comment: `free(buffer);` after `return buffer;` is never executed, see it in a debugger ;) 
I see now: yes, you have to free the memory in the `main` function

Comment: My point is: you can play with fire (re-writing known functions) in your own project, but never in real life.

Comment: @Liviu I edited it so that there isn't any memory leak but it only supports a limited number of characters.

Comment: What if `strlen(str1) >= MAX_STRING_LENGTH`?

Comment: "No null-character is implicitly appended at the end of destination if source is longer than num."
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/

Comment: `buffer[strlen(buffer)] = '\0';` 
Is there something strange in this line ? Guess how strlen works ;) !
I'll be back on Monday, have a nice week-end!

Comment: I think that should work, I'll re-watch when I'm back! You can add `MAX_STRING_LENGTH`  as a parameter to `strcat_const` (with another name, of course).

Comment: It is a disaster :(, you return the address of a stack variable (the `buffer` variable is defined only inside `strcat_const`). I think you should stay with the dynamic allocation solution

Answer (score 1):

Try something similar to this:

```C
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  // Insert code here...
  char firstname[100], secondname[100];
  printf("Enter First Name: ");
  fgets(firstname, 100, stdin);
  printf("Enter Second Name: ");
  fgets(secondname,100,stdin);
  firstname[strlen(firstname)-1]= '\0';
  printf("fullname is %s %s", firstname, secondname);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a char[fixed_size] rather than a char*, you can use a single, creative macro to do it all at once with a `<<cout<<like` ordering ("rather %s the disjointed %s\n", "than", "printf style format").  If you are working with embedded systems, this method will also allow you to leave out malloc and the large `*printf` family of functions like `snprintf()` (This keeps dietlibc from complaining about *printf too)

```
#include <unistd.h> //for the write example
//note: you should check if offset==sizeof(buf) after use
#define strcpyALL(buf, offset, ...) do{ \
    char *bp=(char*)(buf+offset); /*so we can add to the end of a string*/ \
    const char *s, \
    *a[] = { __VA_ARGS__,NULL}, \
    **ss=a; \
    while((s=*ss++)) \
         while((*s)&&(++offset<(int)sizeof(buf))) \
            *bp++=*s++; \
    if (offset!=sizeof(buf))*bp=0; \
}while(0)

char buf[256];
int len=0;

strcpyALL(buf,len,
    "The config file is in:\n\t",getenv("HOME"),"/.config/",argv[0],"/config.rc\n"
);
if (len<sizeof(buf))
    write(1,buf,len); //outputs our message to stdout
else
    write(2,"error\n",6);

//but we can keep adding on because we kept track of the length
//this allows printf-like buffering to minimize number of syscalls to write
//set len back to 0 if you don't want this behavior
strcpyALL(buf,len,"Thanks for using ",argv[0],"!\n");
if (len<sizeof(buf))
    write(1,buf,len); //outputs both messages
else
    write(2,"error\n",6);
```

- Note 1, you typically wouldn't use argv[0] like this - just an example
- Note 2, you can use any function that outputs a char*, including nonstandard functions like itoa() for converting integers to string types.
- Note 3, if you are already using printf anywhere in your program there is no reason not to use snprintf(), since the compiled code would be larger (but inlined and significantly faster)

Answer (score 1):

```
int main()
{
    char input[100];
    gets(input);

    char str[101];
    strcpy(str, " ");
    strcat(str, input);

    char *p = str;

    while(*p) {
       if(*p == ' ' && isalpha(*(p+1)) != 0)
           printf("%c",*(p+1));
       p++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This was my solution

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

char *strconcat(int num_args, ...) {
    int strsize = 0;
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, num_args);
    for (int i = 0; i < num_args; i++) 
        strsize += strlen(va_arg(ap, char*));

    char *res = malloc(strsize+1);
    strsize = 0;
    va_start(ap, num_args);
    for (int i = 0; i < num_args; i++) {
        char *s = va_arg(ap, char*);
        strcpy(res+strsize, s);
        strsize += strlen(s);
    }
    va_end(ap);
    res[strsize] = '\0';

    return res;
}
```

but you need to specify how many strings you're going to concatenate

```
char *str = strconcat(3, "testing ", "this ", "thing");
```