# strcat segmentation fault

Tags: c, strcat

The second call to `strcat` here is generating a segmentation fault, why?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>  
#include <pthread.h>

int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
         char command[250];

         //if(scanf("%199s", command) == 1)

            gets(command);
            puts(command);

         int pipeIntId; 

         char whitespaceseparator[2]=" ";

         char pidstring [30];

         int pid= getpid(); 

         sprintf(pidstring,"%d", pid);

         char * whitespace_and_pid;

         whitespace_and_pid = strcat(whitespaceseparator,pidstring);  


         char * command_and_pid; 

         command_and_pid=strcat(command,whitespace_and_pid); // here's the problem, I guess


          if((mkfifo("pipe"/*pipeName*/,0666))==-1) 
          {
              perror("error creating pipe 1");
          exit(1);
          }

         if((pipeIntId=open("pipe",/*pipeName*/O_WRONLY))==-1)
         {
          perror("error creating pipe 2");
          exit(1);
         }


         int written;

         written=write(pipeIntId,command_and_pid,250); // send the command + the pid


         close(pipeIntId);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I solved the issue using the first answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308695/c-string-concatenation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried your code, and also see the segfault on the second `strcat()`.  I found that `command[250]` is allocated immediately after `whitespaceseparator[2]` on the stack on my system:

```
(gdb) p &whitespaceseparator 
$1 = (char (*)[2]) 0xbf90acd4
(gdb) p &command
$2 = (char (*)[250]) 0xbf90acd6
```

e.g. (here `command` begins `"foo..."`), things are layed out like this:

```
 whitespaceseparator
  |
  |      command
  |       |
  v       v
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|' '| 0 |'f'|'o'|'o'|'.'|'.'|'.'| ...
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

I can't guarantee that the same happens on your system (layout of locals on the stack may vary even between different versions of the same compiler), but it seems likely.  On mine, here is exactly what happens:

As others have said, `strcat()` appends the second string to the first (and the result will be equal to the first argument).  So, the first `strcat()` overflows `whitespaceseparator[]` (and returns `whitespaceseparator` as `whitespace_and_pid`):

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|' '|'1'|'2'|'3'|'4'| 0 |'.'|'.'| ...
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

The second `strcat()` tries to append `whitespace_and_pid` (== `whitespaceseparator`) to the string at `command`.  The first character of the copy will overwrite the terminating 0 of the string at `command`:

```
  |    ===copy===>    |
  v                   v
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|' '|'1'|'2'|'3'|'4'|' '|'.'|'.'| ...
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

The copy continues...

```
      |    ===copy===>    |
      v                   v
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|' '|'1'|'2'|'3'|'4'|' '|'1'|'.'| ...
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+

          |    ===copy===>    |
          v                   v
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|' '|'1'|'2'|'3'|'4'|' '|'1'|'2'| ...
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

and will carry on copying `" 1234 1234 1234"`... until it falls off the end of the process address space, at which point you get a segfault.

Answer (score 3):

`strcat` doesn't do what you think. It modifies the string pointed to by its first parameter. In this case, that string is contained in a 2-byte array, which is therefore overrun.

Comment: Oh, I got that from here http://www.thinkage.ca/english/gcos/expl/c/lib/strcat.html. I'm curious about why it does work the first time it's run.

Comment: I don't think it does "work" the first time it's run: copying `pidstring` to the end of `whitespaceseparator` is undefined behavior, that doesn't mean it necessarily crashes straight away. Matthew's answer has a very plausible explanation why you would see a crash on the line you indicate, assuming your implementation does the same as his.

Comment: No, I don't mean it works using this case of pidstring with whitespaceseparator. It works when used the first time it's run with a buffer of sufficient size, changing the size of whitespaceseparator in this case to a big value won't make it work either.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid buffer overflow errors, but use `strcat` you should to use `strncat` function.

Answer (score 1):

Your gets call could have added sufficient characters already to cause undefined behavior at about anytime.

Answer (score 1):

`whitespaceseparator` isn't big enough to contain the concatenated string, so you're causing undefined behaviour.

Using `gets` is normally frowned upon, too.

Answer (score 1):

`strcat` is generally unsafe because it can happily overrun buffers, like it does in your case.

First of all, `whitespaceseparator` is only two bytes large? Are you sure that's what you want? And you concatenate `pidstring` to it? I think you got the arguments mixed up.

In general though, `strcat` will cause hard-to-debug crashes if you're not very careful with your buffer sizes. There are safer alternatives.

Comment: Such as? An example would be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

"String concatenation" is an idiom you should drop when learning C. Not only does it lead to a lot of bugs with overflowing buffers; it's also super inefficient. In your code, you could just have included the space in the `snprintf` format string (you should be using it in place of `sprintf`).

Whenever possible, try to assemble a string entirely in one step using `snprintf`. This consolidates all of the buffer length checking into one place and makes it really hard to get wrong. You can also call `snprintf` with a 0 size argument to get the length that the combined string would be, in order to find out what size to allocate, if the size of the output is not known in advance (you should allocate one more byte than this length so that the null terminator does not truncate your output).