# string run time error working only with getchar why?

Tags: c, string, visual-studio-2013, getchar

> i am using ***visual studio 2013 for desktop*** and i have run time fail with the string i don't know why this isn't working.

```
    int main(void)
    {
         char string[MAX1] = "THANK ";
         char you[MAX2] = "u";
         strncat(string, you, 1); //without fix this line or the next one
         printMessage(string); 
         return 0;
    }
```

> it is running only when i am putting **getchar** at the end.
>   it is working with other programs like notepad++.
>
> MAX1=7.
>   MAX2=2.

Comment: What's `MAX`? I bet it's less than 7...

Comment: `MAX` must be `>= 8` in order to store the trailing NUL

Comment: `print.Message` does not smell C.....

Comment: @SouravGhosh - Now, now. It could be a global object with a field that is a function pointer, can't it :P

Comment: `notepad++`...I mean really?

Comment: hey until notepad

Comment: @StoryTeller Hah...I was thinking of `typedef`... :P

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is this simple strcat crashing at runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27872079/why-is-this-simple-strcat-crashing-at-runtime)

Answer (score 0):

the concatenated contents of string[] (if it worked) would be THANK u'\0' I.E. 8 characters.

however, only 7 characters were allocated.

The call to strcat() will not stop, so writes beyond the bounds of the array string[]. The result is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

However, when using the strncat() the trailing NUL byte will not be copied. so string[] is now a unterminated char array. and the call to printMessage() will not know where to stop printing characters, Again undefined behavior.