# C: creating new file extensions based on a filename

Tags: c, string, strcat

I would like to name output files based on a base filename with a different extension.  In C psuedo-code:

```
a_file = fopen(filename + ".dt1","wt");
b_file = fopen(filename + ".dt2","wt");
c_file = fopen(filename + ".dt3","wt");
```

I tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308695/c-string-concatenation) example using `strncat`, but my program keeps appending to `filename`.

```
f1=fopen(strcat(filename,".dt1"),"wt");
f2=fopen(strcat(filename,".dt2"),"wt");
f3=fopen(strcat(filename,".dt3"),"wt");
```

This outputs:

```
filename.dt1
filename.dt1.dt2
filename.dt1.dt2.dt3
```

I need the end result to look like:

```
filename.dt1
filename.dt2
filename.dt3
```

Comment: Can't u use a different variable every time, thus having one variable as fileName and using the same string stored in fileName the other types since according to the help of strcat, it changes the contents of the destination string

Comment: Can't you just increment the last character each time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kind of a pain with standard C libs, but this is the way I would do it.

```
    char *fn = malloc(strlen(filename+5)); // Allocate a string with enough space
                                           // for the extensions.

    sprintf(fn, "%s.dt1", filename);       // Copy the name with extensions into fn.
    a_file = fopen(fn,"wt");               //
    sprintf(fn, "%s.dt2", filename);       //
    b_file = fopen(fn,"wt");               //
    sprintf(fn, "%s.dt3", filename);       //
    c_file = fopen(fn,"wt");               //

    free(fn); // Free the memory gained from malloc.
```

Comment: Thanks.  Your code worked fine, although no explanation. :(  Your code with explanations from pb2q and Sebastian Paaske Tørholm above helped me understand how strcat works.

Answer (score 7):

Your code is working as expected considering that [`strcat`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat) appends the extension to the given string. You're using only one string, and so the extensions get stacked upon one another.

Here's one way to do this, amending your posted code which uses a single string for `filename`:

```
size_t len = strlen(filename);
f1 = fopen(strcat(filename, ".dt1"), "wt");
filename[len] = '\0';
f2 = fopen(strcat(filename, ".dt2"), "wt");
filename[len] = '\0';
f3 = fopen(strcat(filename, ".dt3"), "wt");
```

Setting this index to `\0` effectively truncates `filename` back to the original string between calls.

Note that `filename` **must** be large enough to contain the appended extensions - room for **4** additional characters - and that by doing this you'll lose the intermediate file names after opening each file.

Alternately, if your extensions will only differ in the last character:

```
size_t len = 0;
f1 = fopen(strcat(filename, ".dt1"), "wt");
len = strlen(filename);
filename[len - 1] = '2';
f2 = fopen(filename), "wt");
filename[len - 1] = '3';
f3 = fopen(filename, "wt");
```

The same caveats as above apply.

Note: this answer assumes that `filename` has been allocated correctly and with sufficient space to store the string lengths being used, as mentioned above.

Comment: It might be helpful to note why he is getting his problem.  He is appending them on top of each other because he is reusing the same string instead of creating a source string.

Comment: We know nothing of how storage is allocated for `filename` - lots of potential for buffer overruns and it to go bang.

Answer (score 7):

That's because `strcat` writes directly to the buffer of the first string.

The easiest way is probably to use [`snprintf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf) to join the two strings together:

```
snprintf(filename_a, n+4, "%s.dt1", filename);
snprintf(filename_b, n+4, "%s.dt2", filename);
snprintf(filename_c, n+4, "%s.dt3", filename);
```

Here, `filename` is of length `n` (including the trailing `\0`), and `filename_a`, `filename_b` and `filename_c` are buffers of length at least `n+4`.

(You could also use `sprintf`, but it's always good to be careful.)

Comment: +1: even better, if his compiler supports C99, is to use `snprintf`

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2010, and it doesn't know the function, snprintf.  I just used sprintf.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much reasonable output of yours I would say:

```
char * strcat ( char * destination, const char * source );
```

> Appends a copy of the source string to the destination string. The terminating null character in destination is overwritten by the first character of source, and a new null-character is appended at the end of the new string formed by the concatenation of both in destination.

So, character array pointed to by `filename` is both returned from `strcat` and gets modified with concatenation result.

Very easy fix is to remember filename length before modification and then:

```
filename[filename_length_before_modification] = '\0';
```

this will effectively cut appended extension and get you back to starting point

Comment: How do I find out the length of 'filename' (array)?   I assume doing something like int len = sizeof(filename)?  And then filename[int] = '\0'?

Comment: better use strlen(filename). sizeof(filename) at its best can return total size of the array and then you will be writing past its boundary. Depending on how you declared it it may also just return sizeof(char*)

Answer (score 1):

A more efficent way.  It only copies the extension each time.  It can be made even more efficient if we assume that only the last character changes (see pb2q's [second solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11836102/1166181)).

(Untested, off by one likely)

```
size_t len = strlen(filename);
char *buf = malloc(len+4); // Allocate a string with enough space for the
                           // extensions.
strcpy(buf, filename);
char *ext = buf+len // Get a pointer to where the extension starts.

strcpy(ext, ".dt1");             // Copy the name with extensions into fn.
FILE *a_file = fopen(buf, "wt"); //
strcpy(ext, ".dt2");             // 
FILE *b_file = fopen(buf, "wt"); //
strcpy(ext, ".dt3");             // 
FILE *c_file = fopen(buf, "wt"); //

free(buf); // Free the memory gained from malloc.
```