# error: invalid operands to binary + char *

Tags: c, char

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C String Concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308695/c-string-concatenation)

have the following code:

```
        char *doencode(const unsigned char *input, int length)
        {
        //irrelevant code
        }

        char *fname, *lname;
        char *encoded, *name;

        name = fname + "|" + lname;
        encoded = doencode(name, 30);
```

and I get this error: invalid operands to binary +

***How can I combine fname & | & lname?***

Comment: Even if it did compile, it wouldn't work. `name` is not allocated anywhere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot concatenate `char*` and `char[]` (the `"|"`) or any permutation of using `+`. Use [`strncat()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncat) or [`snprintf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) instead and ensure the destination buffer has enough memory to store the final string.

Comment: will it be easier if I replace | with \0 ?

Comment: @SamReina, nope. You still need to use a function to concatenate strings. Replacing the `"|"` with a `"\0"` changes nothing regarding the types involved.

Answer (score 4):

the C is not like java script. This is not correct in c:

```
name = fname + "|" + lname;
```

you can do it in this way:

```
sprintf(name,"%s|%s", fname, lname);
```

The `name` pointer should be pointed to sufficient memory space.

```
name = malloc(strlen(fname)+strlen(lname) + 2);
```

+2: +1 for `"|"` and +1 for `null` at the end of the string

Example

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char *fname, *lname, *name;

    printf("Enter your first name: ");
    scanf ("%ms", &fname);

    printf("Enter your last name: ");
    scanf (" %ms", &lname);

    name = malloc(strlen(fname)+strlen(lname) + 2);
    sprintf(name,"%s|%s", fname, lname);

    printf("name = %s\n",name);

}
```

Comment: This assumes that `name` is pointing at enough space, i.e. it must be a valid pointer and there will be no bounds-checking.

Comment: indeed, I will update my answer with that

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply add strings together in C because strings are actually just pointers to character arrays.  What you have to do is allocate storage for a new string and copy the two strings per character into it.