# Trying to split stdin char[] by ','

Tags: c, split, stdin

I am very new to C. I writing some code to try and separate a stdin string by commas, but I am not sure how to best do this.

Basically, I have some data that will be typed in by the user in the following format:

> **UserID** (char[]),   **00:00:00** (for time,(char[]),   **MeasurementID** (char[]),   **readingValue** (double)

I need to separate out these values so that I can assign them each to a variable. I have some code written where I have *attempted* to do this, however, I know that it is not quite right.

```
char buffer [1024];
char input[];
scanf("%s", input);


int temp = 0;
int timekeeper = 0;
char userID[];
char timestamp[];
char measurementID[];
double value;

for(temp = 0; temp < sizeof(input); temp++){
    char val[1024];
    while(input[temp] != ','){
        val += input[temp];
    }
    if(timekeeper == 0){
        userID = val;
    }
    else if(timekeeper == 1){
        timestamp = val;
    }
    else if(timekeeper == 2){
        measurementID = val;
    }
    else if(timekeeper == 3){
        value = (double)val;
    }
    timekeeper++;
    
}
```

These are the errors I am getting, if they are any help.

> exp.c:87:7: error: invalid operands to binary + (have ‘char[1024]’ and
> ‘int’)
>
> exp.c:90:6: error: incompatible types when assigning to type
> ‘char[1024]’ from type ‘char *’
>
> exp.c:93:13: error: incompatible types
> when assigning to type ‘char[1024]’ from type ‘char *’
>
> exp.c:96:8:
> error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[1024]’ from
> type ‘char *’
>
> exp.c:99:3: error: pointer value used where a floating
> point value was expected

Comment: Never ever use `scanf("%s", input);` Use `fgets` instead.

Comment: Here `char input[];`  array size is missing.

Comment: You cannot extend character strings using the + in C.

Comment: regarding this line: `scanf("%s", input);`  1) always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  2) when using the `%s` input/conversion specifier, always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier so the user cannot overrun the input buffer.  Such overrun is undefined behavior and can/will lead to a seg fault event.  Note: the `scanf()` will stop inputting characters at the first occurrence of a `white space char (for instance a space), so the whole line would not be input.  Suggest using `fgets()` or `getline()`

Comment: this kind of statement: `char userID[];` will define a pointer to char, with the pointer not being initialized to point to anything in particular.  I.E. change that declaration to something like `char userID[ 20 ];`

Comment: suggest learning how to use `strtok()`

Comment: this kind of line: `val += input[temp];` will not work, however you might try:` char val[1024];  val[0] = '\0';` along with: `val[ strlen(val)] = input[temp]l  and finally `val[ strlen(val)] = '\0';`

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have misunderstood how strings work in C.

Doing something like

```
val += input[temp];
```

isn't valid C code. You don't add characters to a C string like that. There are special function for manipulating strings, e.g. `strncat`, `strncpy` and more.

Also definitions like

```
char userID[];
```

are invalid as there is no array size.

Notice that

```
sizeof(input);
```

will give you the size of the variable but you probably want the length of the string, i.e. use `strlen(input)` instead.

Further you can't convert a string to a double by

```
value = (double)val;
```

Instead look up the `atof` function.

This part

```
while(input[temp] != ','){
    val += input[temp];
}
```

will give you an endless loop as `temp` (and thereby `input[temp]`) doesn't change.

I'll recommend that you take a look at this answer [Split string with delimiters in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210528/split-string-with-delimiters-in-c) to learn how you split a string into a number of strings.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot concatenate char* and char[] (the "|") or any permutation of using +. Use strncat() or snprintf() instead and ensure the destination buffer has enough memory to store the final string.

Comment: So would that look something like this?

 strncat(val, (char)input[temp], 1024);

Comment: Here is a example....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219418/error-invalid-operands-to-binary-char

Comment: @star_sh00ter, this expression: `(char)input[temp]` has a couple of problems.  1) `input[temp]` is already a single character so no need to cast.  2) the second parameter to `strncat()` must be a pointer, not a char (though it could be a pointer to an array of char)