# how to merge two strings

Tags: c, algorithm

I have the following program which fails to merge the two strings because the string1 does not have enough space to hold the merged string .When string1 doesnt have enough space and without using the additional array to hold merged string how to return a merged string ?

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<string.h>
 int main()
  { 
      void strcat2(char *str1,char *str2);
      strcat2("john","kris");
      getchar();
  }
  void strcat2(char *str1,char *str2)
   {
     for (; *str1++;);
     for (;*str1++ =*str2++;);

  }
```

Comment: So much **undefined behavior**, so little time.

Comment: This could be of use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308695/c-string-concatenation

Comment: use malloc to allocate suitable space to hold the result.

Comment: Either you must allocate more space or you can't do it.

Comment: -fno-writable-strings

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you use `for` loops instead of `while`? And don't write into string literals, never.

Comment: I am confident that you had warnings as part of your compilation.  Recommend that you show them when posting.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this as this is a better one or just allocate more space.:-

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* concat(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    char *result = malloc(strlen(s1)+strlen(s2)+1);

    strcpy(result, s1);
    strcat(result, s2);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Suggest `concat(const char *s1, const char *s2)`.

Answer (score 2):

In C, you have to do your own memory allocation. That means that in general it is not possible for functions to return strings in the way garbage collected languages can.  When you need to return a string from a function, you must either pass in the result string, pre-allocated by the caller, or else allocate it dynamically and rely on the caller to free it.

There's no shortcut in C, you just have to do the work.