# Why does the following C/C++ macro not work?

Tags: c++, macros

It seems to be very simple, but I can't figure it out. Here is question: 
I have a simple function that returns a string:

```
const wchar_t* getCompanyName() { return L"Test Company";};
```

I want to define a macro like the following:

```
#define COMPANY getCompanyName();
#define PRODUCT COMPANY L" in Canada"

const wchar_t * company = COMPANY; 
const wchar_t * product = PRODUCT;
```

I would expect to see the "product" value is "Test Company in Canada", but it only shows 
"Test Company" and string "in Canada" never concat to the product string

Thank you so much for your time, here is the full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

const wchar_t* getCompanyName() { return L"Test Company";};
#define COMPANY getCompanyName();
#define PRODUCT COMPANY L" in Canada"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
    const wchar_t * company = COMPANY; // get Test Company
    const wchar_t * place = PRODUCT; // get Test Company in Canada

    wprintf(company);
    wprintf(place);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because of

```
#define COMPANY getCompanyName();
```

Remove the semicolon:

```
#define COMPANY getCompanyName()
```

To elaborate, the way you have it written:

```
const wchar_t * product = PRODUCT;
```

expands into:

```
const wchar_t * product = getCompanyName(); L" in Canada";
```

The

```
L" in Canada";
```

is a fine expression on its own that does nothing.  Morale of the story: be careful with semicolons in macros, usually they are not necessary, but sometimes they may be.

Comment: In the expansion of PRODUCT to `getCompanyName() L" in Canada". (`prog.cpp:5:25: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before string constant`) http://ideone.com/PcP1ph

Comment: So you're trying to concat the result of a function with a string literal.

Comment: Yes, it is a syntax error.  If you want to concatenate two strings in C, you must use either `strncat`, or similar function, or string objects in C++.

Comment: You may only concatenate two static strings the way you were trying.  Try `#define COMPANY L"Test company"` and then it will work.

Comment: #define COMPANY L"Test company" - yes, it works. But I need the COMPANY to be a function since it needs to return a system runtime value.

Comment: Look up string concatenation in C. For instance:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308695/c-string-concatenation

Comment: thanks again for the reference - the strcat function can do the job for sure. But, it will require to the change the macro #define PRODUCT COMPANY L" in Canada".

Comment: @Max - `strncat` is not suitable for most situations. It will quietly give you a string without a nul terminator if the size of the target array is the same as the number of characters to be copied. So, indeed, use a **similar** function, i.e., `strcat`.

Comment: @user2852910 - `strcat` isn't quite right; the code is dealing in wide-character strings, so it needs `wcscat`.

Comment: @PeteBecker: this is off the topic of the question.  You are wrong about `strncat`, it will always append a 0 byte to the end of the buffer.  You may end up with a truncated string.  But `strcat` has deeper problems where it can cause your buffer to overflow.  Both are horrible (C strings suck), but `strncat` is at least better than `strcat`.  In any case, this is off-topic and ask another question if you would like to discuss this more.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Maybe what I said is not a standard. `strncat` behaves this way according to Posix: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strncat.html but maybe it is different on other platforms.

Comment: @Max - whoops, sorry; I was thinking of `strncpy`. `strncat` always appends a nul character.

Answer (score 2):

String concatenation only works between adjacent *literal* strings. You can do this:

```
const w_char* product = L"This is " "a concatenated string " "constant.";
```

But not this:

```
const char* first = "First";
const char* second = first " Second";
```

So you definitely can't concatenate a literal string to the result of calling a function. And:

```
#define COMPANY getCompanyName()
```

does not call `getCompanyName` and insert it's value into the macro. It just makes `COMPANY` a synonym for `getCompanyName()`.

So `PRODUCT` (even removing the `;` from `COMPANY`) will expand to

```
getCompanyName() L" in Canada."
```

which is a syntax error.

Comment: thank for the comments, makes sense. how to make the macro work - to concat the function returned string value?

Comment: @user2852910: You can't do it with a macro. You need to actually write a function. If you're actually using C++ and not C, then use `std::wstring` and you can concatenate two strings with the `+` operator. That's way easier than C.

Comment: getCompanyName() L" in Canada." is a syntax error, how to fix it and make it work? the ';' will compile, but does not work as we already know

Comment: @user2852910: If you were using C++ and getCompanyName() returned a std::wstring, then you could define `PRODUCT` as `COMPANY + L" in Canada"`. But I think that requires quite a lot of modification to your program, too. In any event, the question you are now asking is very different from the original one, and you might want to try to ask a new question, after thinking through the alternatives a bit.