# fopen with integer in file name

Tags: c, fopen

I have a bunch of files systematically numbered like `Mesh0Coord.dat`, `Mesh0Elem.dat`, `Mesh1Coord.dat`, `Mesh1Elem.dat`, etc. This is what I want to do:

```
int ID;
FILE *fp;

ID = 0; /* could be 0, 1, 2, etc. and so on for the names of the files */

fp = fopen(“Mesh[ID]Coord.dat”, “r”);
```

The `Mesh[ID]Coord` means that the ID integer should be inserted there. Any tips?

Comment: use `strcat`. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308695/c-string-concatenation

Comment: @l19 strcat cannot operate on an int.

Answer (score 6):

```
#define MAXFILENAME 100

int ID;
char fn[MAXFILENAME+1];

ID = 10;    
snprintf(fn, MAXFILENAME, "Mesh%dCoord.dat", ID)

fp = fopen(fn, "r");
```