# How to generate filename sequence

Tags: c, string

I am looking to add multiple parts to a parameter.

Like this, I know know in VB.net i can do

```
messagebox("hello" + textbox1.text) // yields hello and whatever is in textbox1
```

but how would I do this in C?

I tried `&` and `+` but it give me errors.

i want to create 5 files, and use a for loop to create them, counting 1-5

```
ofp = fopen("data" + (loop counter) + ".txt", "r"); // allong those lines...
```

so the file name would be data1.txt;data2.txt;data3.txt so forth.

thanks

Comment: sprintf is what you require to generate a filename

Comment: helper functions like strcpy can help. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308695/c-string-concatenation

Comment: "How to add multiple amounts of info to one parameter?" - to this question, the answer is "use a `struct`". What you are **really** looking for is concatenating strings.

Comment: Please do not repeat tags in question titles.

Comment: take a look at [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf)

Comment: I did not think of using a strcpy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you may use snprintf:

```
char buffer[FILENAME_MAX];
snprintf(buffer,FILENAME_MAX,"data%d.txt",counter+1); //You will probably start counter at 0

buffer[FILENAME_MAX-1]=0;// snprintf may skip null terminator.
FILE* ofp=fopen(buffer,"w");
//...
fclose(ofp);
```

Comment: The second argument to `snprintf()` could be `FILENAME_MAX` (or even better, `sizeof buffer`).