# How to pass names entered by the user as arguments to the function given below?

Tags: c, encryption

This is the part of the code I need help with -

```
include <stdlib.h>
include <time.h>
include <stdio.h>
include "aes.h"

void encrypt(const char *fileIn, const char *fileOut,
const unsigned char *key);

void decrypt(const char *fileIn, const char *fileOut,
const unsigned char *key); 

int main()
{
const unsigned char key[] = "my key";
srand(time(NULL));

aes_init();
encrypt( "main.c", "main.c.encrypted", key);
decrypt("main.c.encrypted", "main.c.decrypted", key); 
return 0;
}
```

---

Right now, what I do is, every time before running the program is... I go to the code and change the name of the file like..

```
encrypt("main.c", "main.c.encrypted", key);
decrypt("main.c.encrypted", "main.c.decrypted", key);
```

or

```
encrypt("trial.doc", "trial.doc.encrypted", key);
decrypt("trial.doc.encrypted", "trial.doc.decrypted", key);
```

---

However, I would like for the user to be able to enter these file names when the program is run.

**HOW CAN I DO THAT?**

Comment: Please explain in detail as I'm a beginner.

Comment: See, e.g., http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/

Comment: I would have your program take the file names as **command-line arguments**. In C these are `argc`/`argv`.

Comment: Also, as I see no C++ in your code, I've removed that tag.

Comment: This is basic, read-a-tutorial stuff. Please read a tutorial or a good beginners book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For passing arguments to the program,

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) { ...
```

is the `main` prototype you want to use, and then you can get at the argument count and arguments themselves.

For example, the following C program prints out all its arguments, including the one representing the executable:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
        printf ("argv[%d] = '%s'\n", i, argv[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

If you run it with:

```
./myprog three point one four one five nine
```

you'll see the output:

```
argv[0] = './myprog'
argv[1] = 'three'
argv[2] = 'point'
argv[3] = 'one'
argv[4] = 'four'
argv[5] = 'one'
argv[6] = 'five'
argv[7] = 'nine'
```

---

The other alternative is to enter them from within the program and, for that, you can use a safe input function such as the one shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023895/how-to-read-string-entered-by-user-in-c/4023921#4023921).

A safe input function will generally use `fgets()` to ensure there's no chance of buffer overflow. The function linked to above has all sorts of other handy features like end-of-file detection, handling of lines that are too long (detecting and correcting) and prompting.

Answer (score 0):

How about using scanf(), so the user can run the program and enter desired file names?

```
printf("Please enter file name to encrypt: ");
char name[80];
scanf("%s", name);
```

then you can copy the string and concat with ".encrypted" or ".decrypted" string like described here: [C String Concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308695/c-string-concatenation)

Comment: You have to be careful with scanf() to input strings: you should use fgets() instead, as it allows you to specify the size of the string. fgets(buffer, 80, stdin) is probably a better solution.