# Concatenate Strings in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, function

My assignment is to concatenate `v1` onto `v2` and the function `my_strcat()` has to be `void`. How can I use a void function to return the concatenated strings?

```
int main(void){
    char v1[16], v2[16];
    int i1, i2;
    printf("Enter First Name: \n");
    scanf("%s", v1);
    printf("Enter Last Name: \n");
    scanf("%s", v2);
    i1 = my_strlen(v1);
    i2 = my_strlen(v2);
    printf("len: %3d - string: %s \n", i1, v1);
    printf("len: %3d - string: %s \n", i2, v2);
    my_strcat(v1, v2);
    printf("Concatenated String: %s \n", v1);
    return 0;
}

void my_strcat (char s1[], char s2[]){
    int result[16];
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while(s1[i] != '\0'){
        ++i;
        result[i]= s1[i];
    }
    while(s2[j] != '\0'){
        ++j;
        result[i+j] = s2[j];
    }
    result[i+j] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308695/how-to-concatenate-const-literal-strings-in-c

Comment: Just pass a buffer (e.g. an array) to the function to store the new string.

Comment: How can I do that? @teppic

Comment: @Cryptic - have a read up on passing arrays to functions. It's easy enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void my_strcat (char s1[], char s2[],char result[]){
    int result[16];
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while(s1[i] != '\0'){
        result[i]= s1[i];
        ++i;
    }
    while(s2[j] != '\0'){
        result[i+j] = s2[j];
        ++j;
    }
    result[i+j] = '\0';
}
```

You can do something like this..I main() declare a third result string whose size is size(v1)+size(v2)+1

```
char result[33];
my_strcat(v1,v2,result);
```

Output:

```
Enter First Name: avinash
Enter Last Name: pandey
len:   7 - string: avinash 
len:   6 - string: pandey 
Concatenated String: avinashpandey
```

Comment: So I need to add the `char result[]` to the function and declare a string in main like `result = v1[s1] + v2[s2] + 1` @avinashpandey.?

Comment: no not like that, take a look at code .What I meant that size of result string should be equal to grater than sum of both strings lengths.Declare result like a normal string but pass it to the function as my_strcat(v1,v2,result).As string is also an array it's get passed as reference , hence any change in result in the function will be reflected back in main().

Comment: When I run the program it gives me weird symbols for the concatenated string @avinashpandey.

Comment: It is because your logic was wrong I have edited in my answer

Comment: How can you take away `char result[]` from the functuin `my_strcat` but still have it?

Comment: Its because result[] is declared in main() I am just passing it to my_strcat.I hope you get the logic...