# C++ Assigning Output of For Loop to a Variable

Tags: c++

I have a for loop that returns the user's input backwards. They enter a string, and the loop reverses it. Here's what it looks like:

```
string input;                          //what user enters
const char* cInput = input.c_str();    //input converted to const char*

for(int i = strlen(cInput) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
   cout << input[i];     //Outputs the string reversed
```

Instead of having `cout << input[i]`, how can I set `input[i]` as the value of a new string? Like I want to have a string called `string inputReversed` and set it equal to `input[i]`.

In other words, if `input == hello`, and `input[i] == olleh`, I want to set `inputReversed` equal to `olleh`.

Is this doable? Thanks!

Comment: Consider using [`std::string::size`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/size/) instead of converting to a `const char*` and using `strlen`.

Answer (score 2):

Just declare the output string and append to it, either with `+=` or the `append` member function:

```
string inputReversed;

for(int i = input.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    inputReversed += input[i];         // this
//  inputReversed.append(input[i]);    // and this both do the same thing
```

Note that you don't need `c_str` and `strlen`, you can simply use the `size` or `length` member function.

You can also make the code more readable by using [`std::reverse`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse):

```
string inputReversed = input;
std::reverse(inputReversed.begin(), inputReversed.end());
```

Or [`std::reverse_copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse_copy), since you're making a copy of the original string anyway:

```
string inputReversed;
std::reverse_copy(input.begin(), input.end(), std::back_inserter(inputReversed));
```

Comment: Thanks, I like this method. And I didn't use the reverse function because I wanted to make a palindrome detector as beginner practice :)

Answer (score 2):

```
string inputReversed(input.rbegin(), input.rend());
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understand what you are asking you want to have a variable to store the reversed string and output that?
If so you can just do this

```
string input, InputReversed; 
                         //what user enters
const char* cInput = input.c_str();    //input converted to const char*

for(int i = strlen(cInput) - 1; i >= 0; i--){

    InputReversed += input[i];     

}
cout << InputReversed;  //Outputs the string reversed
```

Answer (score 0):

Going off of this thread may help you.
[How do I concatenate const/literal strings in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308695/how-to-concatenate-const-literal-strings-in-c)

It seems like what you want is to create a new string which at the end of the loop will contain the backwards input.

```
string input;                          //what user enters
const char* cInput = input.c_str();    //input converted to const char*
char inputReversed[len(input)];

for(int i = strlen(cInput) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
   output = strcpy(output, input[i]);     //Outputs the string reversed
```