# Add string to LPTSTR

Tags: c, winapi

I want to add an string to a LPTSTR.

The code is:

```
hSourceFile = CreateFile(
    pszSourceFile,
    FILE_READ_DATA,
    FILE_SHARE_READ,
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
    NULL);
if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != hSourceFile)
{
    _tprintf(
        TEXT("The source plaintext file, %s, is open. \n"),
        pszSourceFile);
}
```

The pszSourceFile is a type of LPTSTR, but i want to add some extra text.

Like (not working)

> pszSourceFile + ".txt"

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Please take a look for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308695/how-to-concatenate-const-literal-strings-in-c) question. Btw, WinAPI is C and not C++.

Comment: Why do you feel the need to support Windows 98? Wouldn't it be better to move into the 21st century and just use Unicode. Don't be tricked into thinking that `TCHAR` is still useful.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the C-style and the use of the Windows API (with `TEXT()` et. al.); use [`_tcscat()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h1x0y282.aspx) or [`_tcsncat()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tbyd7s1y.aspx) (the later requires a buffer size).

For example;

```
TCHAR buffer[1024] = {}; // or '\0'
_tcsncat(buffer, pszSourceFile, 1024);
_tcsncat(buffer, TEXT(".txt"), 1024);
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/915e7d293908776f).

*Warning*; watch out for your buffer overruns. Assuming the "normal" Windows 260 character path file and name limits (`_MAX_PATH`), the buffer needs to cater for that.

For C++ (as originally tagged), an alternative is to use `std::basic_string<TCHAR>` and then the `operator+` (or `+=`) as per usual. The `.c_str()` will get you the resultant string;

```
std::basic_string<TCHAR> buffer(pszSourceFile);
buffer += TEXT(".txt");
auto ptr = buffer.c_str();
```

Comment: Thanks for you comment, but it gives me the error: 'wcscat': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using wcscat_s instead.

Comment: Yes, Windows included a number of more secure versions (MS specific, the warnings can be turned off), you can use those alternatives as well, they will need a length indicator to get to compile and run correctly.

Comment: @DeFix. If you found one of the answers most useful or correct, you should consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

Your particular use case is not a simple "append" but rather an insert/format. Along the same lines as Niall you are using the `TCHAR` macros so I would recommend `_stprintf_s` (or `_sntprintf_s`... see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ce3zzk1k.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396))

```
TCHAR output[SIZE] = {0};
_stprintf_s(output, _T("The %s directory"), pszSourceFile);
```

Of course it depends on what exactly `pszSourceFile` is... if it is a `std::string` then you'll need to use the `c_str()` member to get a pointer, and you'll need to be careful about using `std::string` versus `std::wstring`.