# Directory Open Issue when passing path as parameter

Tags: c++, c

I having an issue with my program which is expected to either ask a user to input a directory path or to use an predefine directory path as an argument so that my program can open that directory.

Asking a user to input the directory path (C:\Users\Desktop\Test) works fine. But I am having an issue when I am passing the file path as argument.

It should be passed as this:

```
char location[1000] = "C:\Users\Desktop\Test";

if ((dir = opendir (location)) != NULL){
```

......
}

But using argument, my program can only open the directory if location is initialised and assigned as this:

```
char location[1000] = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Test";

if ((dir = opendir (location)) != NULL){
```

......
}

However, I need to concatenate location with a filename in another part of my program so that it becomes: C:\Users\Desktop\Test\file.txt

```
It won`t work with: C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Test\\file.txt.
```

char location[1000] can`t be modified as it works well with my code when opening or closing directory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to concatenate const/literal strings in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308695/how-to-concatenate-const-literal-strings-in-c)

Comment: @MooseBoys I have an issue with the: C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Test\\....I need to be able to open the directory when it is like: C:\Users\Desktop\Test\ but windows don`t accept to open it as C:\Users\Desktop\Test\ but with C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Test\\ only.

Comment: are you accepting input from a user? [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) is the reason your former example isn't working...backslash is reserved in string literals.

Comment: @kirinthos I give the user two choices, either to input the path or I define a path. When User input the path, it works well as it is: C:\Users\Desktop\Test\ but with parameter, it only open when it is like: C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Test\\ but I need it to be open with: C:\Users\Desktop\Test\ instead.

Comment: right...well when declaring a _string literal_ "C:\\Users" => C:\Users

Comment: A minimum working test source snippet would go further to explain what you're trying to fix then continued linguistic explanations.

Comment: @kirinthos i tried to do it in another way like: char location[1000];
            strcpy(location,"C:\Users\ASG\Desktop\TEst\"); but i get error: expected ';' before '}' token|

Comment: @Aumnayan i have already tested with string it only worked with char location[1000]; not with string location;

Comment: please, please [read this link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape)

Comment: cool, to you see why the first string is actually want you want? that "\\" => \ and why you got the 'no semi colon' error in your strcpy texampl

Comment: @kirinthos so basically char location[1000] = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Test"; is the same as char location[1000] = "C:\Users\Desktop\Test"; ?

Comment: You need to understand the `\\` is an escape character in string literals.

Comment: Is this question about C or C++?  Please pick one and delete the other tag.