# how to touch a file to a particular location which was #defined

Tags: c

Assume like I have a `#define` something like

```
#define LOCATION /usr/lib/siara/
```

Now i want to touch a file in that location provided I have permissions to create.
I want to do something like this.

```
system("touch $(LOCATION)/myfile.txt")
```

But it is not working. Any idea how to resolve this issue

Comment: can you change the define to `#define LOCATION "/usr/lib/siara/"`? In that case you can use `system("touch "LOCATION"myfile.txt");`.

Comment: The particular answer OP wants is this one:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/32665978/767442

Comment: @jforberg he can do it in compile time as mch's comment

Comment: @MichaelWalz, why is the OP's definition invalid?  There's certainly nothing wrong with the identifier, and I'm missing why `/usr/lib/siara/` would fail to be a sequence of preprocessing tokens, which is the only constraint on that part.  It may indeed not be what he wants, but I think it's valid.

Comment: @JohnBollinger , you are right my comment is wrong, I'll delete it, thanks.