# add string to given command line argument in C

Tags: c, string, concatenation, command-line-arguments

Hello i just started to programm in C and i am trying to read a file and give the file name as argument without the ending .txt . I want to add .txt in my code : ./myexample.exe file

if i use file.txt there is no problem but i dont know how to change argv[1]
i tried char *n = argv[1] + ".txt"; it doesnt works and i dont know anything else..

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
      char *n = argv[1] +".txt";
      FILE *fp1;
      fp1 = fopen(n , "r");
```

Thats what i get if i use `char *n = argv[1]+".txt"`

> error: invalid operands to binary + (have 'char *' and 'char *')

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to concatenate const/literal strings in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308695/how-to-concatenate-const-literal-strings-in-c)

Comment: 1) A pointer is not a string! 2) A pointer is not an array. 3) C does not have a distinct string type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't concatenate strings with +. Use strcpy and strcat:

```
char n[256];
strcpy(n, argv[1]);
strcat(n, ".txt");
```

Make sure that n is large enough to hold the filename + extension.

Comment: 100 is not big enough to hold any filename. Need at least 256 to hold any filename on Linux for instance.

Comment: Thanks for the hint

Comment: It would probably be wise to check if the string fits in the buffer before copying, too.

Answer (score 3):

In your code,

```
 char *n = argv[1] +".txt";
```

does not do what you think it does. In C, the `+` cannot be used to concatenate *strings*.

FYI, from `C11`, chapter  §6.5.6

> For addition, either both operands shall have arithmetic type, or **one operand shall be a
>   pointer to a complete object type and the other shall have integer type.** (Incrementing is
>   equivalent to adding 1.)

Both the operands cannot be of pointer-to-object type.

If you meant to concatenate *strings*, use [`strcat()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat) but make sure

- the destination is modifiable (attempt to modify string literal is UB)
- the destination got enough space to contain the final result (shorter destination lead to access out of bound memory invoking UB, again).

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of annoying to do safely: you need to be careful to make a big enough `char` array to hold the whole string. One way:

```
size_t arglen=strlen(argv[1]);
char* filename=malloc(arglen+5); //Enough to hold the whole string
strcpy(filename,argv[1]);
strcat(filename,".txt");
```

Be sure to `free` the pointer later.