# C: creating file and backup file

Tags: c, string, file

I have a file and I want to make a backup file, with the same name as file but with "aux" at the end. How do I do this? I tried:

```
char *nameFile, *nameAux;
char *aux = aux;
nameAux = nameFile + aux;
```

Which didn't work.. nameFile is given to me by the user, and it's right because I can open/ceate the file with nameFile

Comment: "It didn't work" is never a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just "add" C strings. effectively you've summed pointers.
See [How do I concatenate const/literal strings in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308695/how-do-i-concatenate-const-literal-strings-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

There is no `+` operator for strings in C.

You need to use [`strcat()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/), like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char* filename = "myfile";
    char backup_filename[10];
    strcpy(backup_filename, filename);
    strcat(backup_filename, ".AUX");
    puts(backup_filename);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> myfile.AUX