# Does snprintf/sprintf overwrite the terminating-null of the penultimate argument, just like strcat does?

Tags: c, concatenation, null-terminated

It is clearly written for `strcat`, e.g. [here](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat) and [here](https://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/strcat.3.asp) that, in case,

```
char *strcat(char *s1, const char *s2);
```

then,

> The initial character of s2 overwrites the null character at the end of s1.

But apparently searching a little here for "concatenating strings/literals in C", I stumbled upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/308732/2955790), which states,

> Avoid using strcat in C code. The cleanest and, most importantly, the safest way is to use snprintf:

So, is the same also true for `snprintf/sprintf` that *the first character of the next argument overwrites the null-termination of the previous argument*? I can see no such reference in the [documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf).

Empirically evidence seems to suggest, that both strcat & snprintf act the same way. Or is my assumption wrong?

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    printf( "Test Program Started\n");
    const char* first = "a";
    const char* second = "b";
    const char* third = "c";
    const int merged_length = (strlen(first) + strlen(second) + strlen(third) + 1); // +1 for null-termination

    char* catResult;
    catResult = malloc( merged_length * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(catResult, first);
    strcat(catResult, second);
    strcat(catResult, third);
    catResult[merged_length] = '\0';
    printf("catResult:%s \tstrlen(catResult):%d \t sizeof(catResult):%d\n", 
            catResult, 
            strlen(catResult), 
            sizeof(catResult));
    free(catResult);

    char* snprintfResult;
    snprintfResult = malloc( merged_length * sizeof(char));
    snprintf(snprintfResult, merged_length, "%s%s%s", first, second, third);
    // catResult[merged_length] = '\0'; // not necessary as per documentation
    printf("snprintfResult:%s \tstrlen(snprintfResult):%d \tsizeof(snprintfResult):%d\n", 
            snprintfResult, 
            strlen(snprintfResult), 
            sizeof(snprintfResult));
    free(snprintfResult);
}
```

> Test Program Started
> catResult:abc   strlen(catResult):3      sizeof(catResult):4
> snprintfResult:abc      strlen(snprintfResult):3        sizeof(snprintfResult):4

Comment: @user694733, wooops! my bad! I will edit and correct it. One second.

Comment: @user694733, In the original test-code I had here on the PC I had used `strlen`. Then I wanted to test with `sizeof` and forgot to undo that change before pasting here. Better now?

Comment: The incorrect usage of `snprintf` (similar to `strcat`) is `snprintf(buf, buflen, "%s%s", buf, more_stuff);`. That will "work" with some C library implementations and not with others, but it's Undefined Behaviour according to the standard.

Comment: @rici, ok. I understand. The source and the destination cannot be overlapping, as you show in the snippet in your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `sizeof` like that. While `sizeof("string")` works as you expect, `sizeof(string pointer)` always returns the same value on any given platform (usually 4 or 8).

`const int merged_length = (sizeof(first) + sizeof(second) + sizeof(third) + 1);`

should be

`const int merged_length = (strlen(first) + strlen(second) + strlen(third) + 1);`

When you write `%s` to `snprintf`, it copies the string to the target string without any trailing null. When the null terminator at the end of the format string is reached, the output string is also null terminated.

So, the actual answer to your question is no, because the null was never written after `first`, but the final effect is more like if we answered yes, because both those code fragments do the same thing.

Comment: `When you write %s to snprintf, it copies the string to the target string without any trailing null.` --> that was exactly my question. `So, the actual answer to your question is no, because the null was never written after first` --> thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 2):

`snprintf` and `sprintf` do not append to a prior string the way `strcat` does. They start writing at the beginning of the buffer passed to them.

When writing multiple strings in a single call, as with the format string `"%s%s%s"`, they will write the strings consecutively, with no null characters between them, and ending with a null character.

If you want them to append to an existing string in a buffer named `buffer`, then determine the length of the string, say `n`, and pass `buffer + n` as the first argument instead of `buffer`. (For `snprintf`, note that `n` should also be subtracted from the second argument, which specifies how many bytes are available in the buffer.)

Comment: `When writing multiple strings in a single call, as with the format string "%s%s%s", they will write the strings consecutively, with no null characters between them` --> that was exactly my question. Thanks for the quick answer.