# How to concatenate const char* to get another JSON via https

Tags: json, arduino, char, youtube-api, esp32

I'm trying to get JSON (YouTube Data API) multiple times after a response of JSON using ESP32 board with ArduinoJSON library (to reach activeLiveChatId and comments). But I couldn't concatenate const char value to make new URL. Maybe my code should be wrong hundling const char*.
Could you suggest me the some solution? Below is my draft sketch.

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Fingerprint for demo URL, expires on June 2, 2021, needs to be updated well before this date

char ssid[] = "myssid";       // your network SSID (name)
char password[] = "mypass";  // your network key

#define API_KEY "myapikey"  // your google apps API Token
#define CHANNEL_ID "mychannelid" // makes up the url of channel
#define servername "www.googleapis.com"

WiFiClientSecure client;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  // Set WiFi to station mode and disconnect from an AP if it was previously connected
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.disconnect();
  delay(100);
  // Attempt to connect to Wifi network:
  Serial.print("Connecting Wifi: ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(500);
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
  Serial.println(ip);
  delay(3000);

  if ((WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED)) {
    String url1 = ("https://"servername"/youtube/v3/search?eventType=live&part=id&channelId="CHANNEL_ID"&type=video&key="API_KEY);
    String url2prefix = "https://"servername"/youtube/v3/videos?part=liveStreamingDetails&field=activeLiveChatId&id=";
    String url2postfix = "&key="API_KEY;
    const char* items_0_id_videoId;
    HTTPClient https;
    
    Serial.print("[HTTPS] begin...\n");
    if (https.begin(client, url1)) {  // HTTPS
      Serial.print("[HTTPS] GET...\n");
      // start connection and send HTTP header
      int httpCode = https.GET();
      // httpCode will be negative on error
      if (httpCode > 0) {
        // HTTP header has been send and Server response header has been handled
        Serial.printf("[HTTPS] GET... code: %d\n", httpCode);
        // file found at server
        if (httpCode == HTTP_CODE_OK || httpCode == HTTP_CODE_MOVED_PERMANENTLY) {
          String payload = https.getString();
          DynamicJsonDocument doc(96);
          StaticJsonDocument<64> filter;
          filter["items"][0]["id"]["videoId"] = true;
          DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc, payload, DeserializationOption::Filter(filter));
          if (error) {
            Serial.print(F("deserializeJson() failed: "));
            Serial.println(error.c_str());
            return;
          }
 
          const char* kind = doc["kind"]; // "youtube#searchListResponse"
          const char* etag = doc["etag"]; // 
          const char* regionCode = doc["regionCode"]; // "JP"
          int pageInfo_totalResults = doc["pageInfo"]["totalResults"]; // 1
          int pageInfo_resultsPerPage = doc["pageInfo"]["resultsPerPage"]; // 1
          JsonObject items_0 = doc["items"][0];
          const char* items_0_kind = items_0["kind"]; // "youtube#searchResult"
          const char* items_0_etag = items_0["etag"]; // 
          const char* items_0_id_kind = items_0["id"]["kind"]; // "youtube#video"
          items_0_id_videoId = items_0["id"]["videoId"]; // 

          Serial.printf(
          "ID: %s\n",
          items_0_id_videoId);
        }
      }
    }
    String url2 = url2prefix + items_0_id_videoId + url2postfix;
    //retrieve activeLiveChatId
    if (https.begin(client, url2)) {  // HTTPS
      Serial.print("[HTTPS] GET...\n");
      // start connection and send HTTP header
      int httpCode = https.GET();
      // httpCode will be negative on error
      if (httpCode > 0) {
        // HTTP header has been send and Server response header has been handled
        Serial.printf("[HTTPS] GET... code: %d\n", httpCode);
        // file found at server
        if (httpCode == HTTP_CODE_OK || httpCode == HTTP_CODE_MOVED_PERMANENTLY) {
          String payload = https.getString();
          Serial.println(payload);
          // Stream& input;
          DynamicJsonDocument doc(96);
          StaticJsonDocument<64> filter;
          filter["items"][0]["liveStreamingDetails"]["activeLiveChatId"] = true;
          DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc, payload, DeserializationOption::Filter(filter));

          if (error) {
            Serial.print(F("deserializeJson() failed: "));
            Serial.println(error.c_str());
            return;
          }
  
          const char* items_0_liveStreamingDetails_activeLiveChatId = doc["items"][0]["liveStreamingDetails"]["activeLiveChatId"];
        
          Serial.printf(
          "livechatID: %s\n",
          items_0_liveStreamingDetails_activeLiveChatId
          );
        }
      } else {
        Serial.printf("[HTTP] GET... failed, error: %s\n", https.errorToString(httpCode).c_str());
      }
      https.end();
    } else {
      Serial.printf("[HTTP] Unable to connect\n");
    }
  }
}  

void loop() {
  // wait for WiFi connection
  Serial.println("Wait 10s before next round...");
  delay(10000);
}
```

Comment: It's great that you posted the whole sketch, thank you - a lot of people don't and then there's not enough info to address a question. In this case could you identify some specific lines of code that you're having trouble with and be more clear about what result you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you for your kind comment. I thought that the middle of the code:
`String url2 = url2prefix + items_0_id_videoId + url2postfix;`
is problem and I want to know how to concatenate those strings including "items_0_id_videoId" which obtained from the previous JSON value.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting read-only strings of type `const char*` from your JSON parser - that's OK. You can concatenate them without restriction, but you have to provide memory to hold the result of the concatenation.

There are a few ways to solve this

1. `strncat()` (good old-fashioned C). Have a look at this [thread explaining strcat()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308695/how-do-i-concatenate-const-literal-strings-in-c). In essence, allocate enough memory to hold the new string and then store the concatenation result there (error handling omitted for clarity). Assuming the strings you want to concatenate are `str1` and `str2`:

```
    const size_t cat_buf_len = strlen(str1) + strlen(str2) + 1;
    char* cat_buf = (char*) malloc(cat_buf_len);
    strncpy(cat_buf, str1, cat_buf_len);
    strncat(cat_buf, str2, cat_buf_len - strlen(cat_buf));
    // ... use the concatenated string in cat_buf
    free(cat_buf);
```

2. `snprintf()` (C). Similar to `strcat()` - a bit easier on the eyes, but not as efficient.

```
    const size_t cat_buf_len = strlen(str1) + strlen(str2) + 1;
    char* cat_buf = (char*) malloc(cat_buf_len);
    snprintf(cat_buf, cat_buf_len, "%s%s", str1, str2);
    // ... use the concatenated string in cat_buf
    free(cat_buf);
```

3. Arduino `String` (C++). The String type operates on heap, manages its own memory and is a bit easier to use. It does risk fragmenting the heap, though, if not used carefully.

```
    String cat_str = String(str1) + str2;
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation enhancing my knowledge!
I could understand your comment and solved following No.3!
Thank you so much again!

Comment: That's great to hear, have fun! As they say, an upvote is the best thanks ;)